# which one to use between node-sass vs node-sass-middleware?

Tags: node-sass, express-generator

```
express --ejs --css sass --git
```

above command install node-sass-middleware npm automatically.

since I found that a lot of people use node-sass npm, I wonder what the differences are between those two.

I have searched some, and many articles seems to recommmend using node-sass npm.

so why then express generator supports node-sass-middleware npm?

any advice might be helpful.

Comment: any ideas with this issue..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NodeSassMiddleware basically includes the node-sass package automatically when you will install it as package, so use node-sass-middleware package.

Comment: appreciate for your comment. before receiving your answer, I asked another guy for this issue. and he said "recommend to compile scss file before on-the-fly and also recommend using webpack module bundler". which means not recommend using node-sass-middleware. what do you think of it?

Comment: Webpack is different technology. Im agree with that but if you are using standalone then go with node saas middleware

Comment: Node sass middleware and webpack node sass both compile sass n scss files.

Comment: appreciate for your advice.
node-sass middleware and node sass both compile sass files, different only in terms of when to compile right? on-the-fly or before.

Comment: Thank you for appreciation, both can compile on the fly and before and after. WebPack is a bundler module and it utilizes the node-sass package to compile the SASS/SCSS files. If you are not using WebPack then node-sass is the only way to compile files for nodejs app.